# Kernel selection using yocto

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

I am building images for i.MX board using Yocto. My requirement is to build specific kernel for the board.

After downloading from Freescale Yocto repository site, I could see recipes for multiple kernels.

Can you guide me to understand how yocto will decide which kernel to build. I mean where Yocto configured to build specific kernel out of the available kernel recipes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify which kernel to build with bitbake/yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761635/how-to-specify-which-kernel-to-build-with-bitbake-yocto)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select which kernel to build in your machine configuration, see [BSP manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bsp-guide/bsp-guide.html#bsp-filelayout-machine) and for example [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761635/how-to-specify-which-kernel-to-build-with-bitbake-yocto/26781763)

Basically, for selecting kernel you can add

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "my-kernel-recipe"
```

To your `mymachine.conf`.

Answer (score 4):

You should have or create kernel bb layer for having kernel source.

Once you have kernel source, add following in your local.conf file.

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ?= "<bb_layer_name>"
PREFERRED_VERSION_<bb_layer_name> ?= "<version>"
```

E.g.

```
mkdir -p meta-imx/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx_4.11.bb
```

add whatever you want in bb file.

```
vi build/local.conf

# kernel preference    
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ?= "linux-imx"
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-imx ?= "4.11%"
```

Once you are good with it you can merge build/local.conf to your target such as local.conf.sample or what ever name you have given.

Answer (score 2):

Add preferred kernel version in *`build/conf/local.conf`* file

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-imx = "3.14%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `meta-layer/conf/machine` then open your `selected-machine.conf` file in and there you will find the macro variable

`PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel`

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_<bb_layer_name> ?= "<version>"
```

the meta-layer developers written the default `kernel & version` here. If.